# How to handle imageview to download image from url when on screen view

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-asynctask, imageview

I'm developing an android app, which dynamically download the images from remote urls. I have a web service that fetches a list of image urls for my app.

i use the for loop to create imageview to show on a device screen

Here is code example

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i++ ) {
    ImageView imgv  = new ImageView(context);
    setImage(imgv, imageUrls[i]); // use AsyncTask

    linearLayoutVertical.addView(imgv); // add to its parent 
}
```

I want to prevent all the images download immediately when it set to imageview. In the other word, make it works like listview. only show image when it's in screen view. But my problem is it download all images.

[image]

And i have some reason to not use listview, many thanks.

Comment: What is your reason to not use `ListView`? If you don't use it, you'll basically have to make a custom `ListView` yourself.

Comment: Using picasso or glide image loading libraries it can be accomplished easily. Asynctask is comparatively slower. Take a look at those libraries, and I agree with Eric on usage of ListView or RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `NetworkImageView` found in [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) library.

You can use `ListView` or `RecyclerView` for displaying your data, where each cell/item will have a `NetworkImageView`. `NetworkImageView` is perfect for your requirement where you want to load images only when scroll, it is called **Lazy loading**. For using `NetworkImageView` you have to use a `ImageLoader`. Have a look into [this](https://github.com/priyankapaul/TipstatChallenge) or [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) projects for your reference.

`NetworkImageView` has a beautiful method `setImageUrl` that would save a lot of effort for you.

```
articlePhoto.setImageUrl(image_url, imageLoader);
```

BTW, `NetworkImageView` could be used irrespective of using `ListView` `RecyclerView` or any scroll view.